# how to divide sample rate frequency by 10 bands for equalization

Tags: audio, signal-processing, sample-rate

How to divide sample rate frequency by 10 bands for equalization.
For example i have audio pcm with 44100 hz and 1 byte per sample. How can i understand which sample is related with specified band. And how to divide samples to bands.

Can you give me explanation or link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two common approaches for this:

1. Use a [filter bank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_bank). You need to design 10 [band-pass filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandpass_filter). All
   the filters receive the full bandwudth input and the output of each
   filter is a sub-band containing only the frequencies of interest for
   that band. For equalization purposes you can then scale the
   amplitude of each filter output and then re-combine the scaled
   outputs.
2. Use [FFT + IFFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fft). Use a (forward) FFT to
   convert your time domain data into the frequency domain. Modify the
   amplitudes in each frequency domain bin. Apply inverse FFT to get
   equalized data back into the time domain. You'll need to choose a
   sufficiently large FFT size (N) to get the required frequency
   resolution for your equalization bands. You'll also need to use an
   overlap technique to avoid discontinuities between successive
   frames.

Comment: -(1/2) In general, applying a non-rectangular window before using a zero-padded FFT/IFFT for overlap-add or overlap-save fast convolution filtering is incorrect.

Comment: You're right of course - reference to window function removed.

Comment: @PaulR: I am searching for the same 10 band equalizer for android. Do you have any idea about how to make it for android music player?

Comment: @iDroid: which part are you having difficulty with ? You might want to post a question about your specific problem.

Comment: @PaulR: I dont have more knowledge about signal processing and sample ratting. I am using Equalizer class of android sdk. Where i am getting only 5 band. Instead of i want to have 10 band.I dont know how to made it.

Comment: @iDroid: OK - well it sounds like you have a steep learning curve to climb unless you can find some ready-made third-party code.

Answer (score 0):

Do a search on "quadrature mirror filter" or "perfect reconstruction".  This paper looks to be as good a place as any to begin:

http://authors.library.caltech.edu/5463/1/VAIieeeasspm87.pdf